# Adding functionality to kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, cryptoapi

I am trying to implement a LKM (for educational purposes) and is going fine until I try to add some functionality to it. Currently, module echos back the string received and I am trying to make modifications to it.

```
ssize_t echo_write(struct file *fileptr, const char __user *buff, size_t cmax, loff_t *offptr) {
ssize_t cwrite = 0, error = 0;
struct echo_dev *echo_device = fileptr->private_data;
char *kbuff;
printk(KERN_INFO "  -K- echo_write was invoked!\n");
if(echo_device->f_write) {
    kfree(kbuff);
    error = echo_device->f_write;
    echo_device->f_write = 0;
    return error;
}

kbuff = kzalloc(cmax+1, GFP_KERNEL);
if(!kbuff) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "  -K- echo_write could NOT alloc memory!\n");
    return -1;
}

printk(KERN_INFO "  -K- echo_write was invoked!\n");
cwrite = cmax - copy_from_user(kbuff, buff, cmax);
echo_device->cwrite += cwrite;
kbuff[cwrite] = '\0';

if(cwrite == 0) {
    echo_device->f_write = 0;
    return -EFAULT; //No char written, return error
}
else if(cwrite < cmax)
    echo_device->f_write = -EFAULT; //Flags error to return on next call
else
    echo_device->f_write = 0;

printk(KERN_NOTICE "      -KW- %s", kbuff);

kfree(kbuff);
return cwrite;
}
```

Here buff is the received data and is being copied to kbuff. I want to expose buff variable to sha256 hashing and assign to kbuff. I tried to implement OpenSSL to the module but I kept getting unknown symbol errors. From a search I got ;

```
Compile flags: -lssl -lcrypto

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int main (void) {
const char *s = "test1";
unsigned char *d = SHA256(s, strlen(s), 0);

int i;
for (i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    printf("%02x", d[i]);
putchar('\n');

return 0;
}
```

which compiles and runs as expected but I was unable to embed it to echo_write function. I would appreciate guidance from experienced users. Is it possible to add the sha256 code to the function ?

Comment: openssl is not intended to be used in the kernel. It is a user level library. You can't link a user level library into the kernel.

Comment: You know how to use OpenSSL, you have to include the header file *and link with the library*?

Comment: The kernel has its own crypto API. See [Code Example For Use of Operational State Memory With SHASH](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/crypto/api-samples.html#code-example-for-use-of-operational-state-memory-with-shash) for example usage. In that example, you would need to set `hash_alg_name` in `test_hash()` to `"sha256"` and make sure that `digest` points to a buffer at least 32 bytes long (`SHA256_DIGEST_SIZE` from `#include <crypto/sha.h>`). The functions such as `crypto_alloc_shash()` are declared by `#include <crypto/hash.h>`.

Comment: You free kbuff before assigning it.